# Change a card's title, based on the user's input with bootbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootbox

**Hi,here is my scenario for the Question**

I have a button.

When the button is clicked on a web page, a modal will pop up(generated by Bootbox.js), which contain an input text area and a confirm button.

**Here is what I want to achieve:**
Create a Card with a Title based on the user's input:

Once the user have key-in some text for the input, and clicked on the confirm button afterward, the modal will disappear,generating a card with a title(same as the user's input) on the web page.

**What I have tried:**

With bootbox and Bootstrap 4:

```
     var addGroup_data = function () {
        let addGroup = $('#addGroup').html();
        Rule_add = bootbox.dialog({
            title: 'Add New Card',/**/
            message: addCard,
            centerVertical: true,
            // size: 'large',
            buttons: {
                confirm: {
                    label: 'Confirm',
                    className: 'justify-content-center btn-primary',
                    var id = $('.modal-body #groupId').val();
                       }
                        });
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>Name: <input type="text" name="user"></p>
            <h5 id="groupId">card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">content.</p>
            <a href="javascript" class="btn btn-primary">modal popup</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('body').on('click','#groupId',function(){
    let inputValue = $(this).val();
    let text = $(this).find('#groupId')

    /*$('body').on('click', ' .modal btn' ,function() {
        $("#groupId").append(gcardTitle);
    })*/

    $(".modal btn").click(function(){
        $("#groupCardTitle").append(inputValue);
      });

})
```

Question :
It seems like I will never get the value of input and I have no clue.

Comment: did you tried `$("#groupCardTitle").text(inputValue)` ??

Comment: Shouldnt $('body'). be $('card-body').?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Akhil, appreciated. However, before I can test if it works,I can't assured that the $(".modal btn") really selected the button inside the modal.

Comment: Hi,Grumpy: the $('body') is the body section of html,I use selector to select the body>#groupId, so I can make sure that I did select the id I want.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with `var id = $('.modal-body #groupId').val();`? - that code isn't valid there.